# multi dimensional array formated echo by index

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => none
            [2] => none
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
            [1] => 2
            [2] => none
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Hello experts i have this array from check boxes and i want to echo it by index values i.e. in order of keys like all 0 index values in one pocket and 1 index values in one pocket for example `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]] with its values like [[1, none, none], [none, 2, 2], [none, none, 3]]`
Please can somebody help me ?

Comment: Well, have you considered using `for` or `foreach` operator ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. well i tried but i am not an expert of php could you please show me how to do that i can fallow up and i need to insert output to mysql. When i run a foreach loop it give my 0,1,2 of one sub array then 0,1,2 of second then 0,1,2 of third but i need to output all 0 values, all 1 values, all 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myArray = array(   1 => array( 0 => 1, 1 => "none", 2 => "none"),                   
                    2 => array( 0 => "none", 1 => 2, 2 => "none"),                   
                    5 => array( 0 => "none", 1 => 2, 2 => 3) );  

$newArray = array();
foreach( $myArray AS $masterIndex => $childArray )
{
    foreach( $childArray AS $index => $value )     
    {
        if( !isset($newArray[$index]) )
        {
            $newArray[$index] = array();
        }
        $newArray[$index][] = $value;
    }
}

$outputValues = "["; 

foreach( $newArray AS $childArray ) 
{     
    $outputValues .= "[" . implode(",", $childArray) . "],";
} 
$outputValues = substr($outputValues, 0, strlen($outputValues) -1) . "]";
echo $outputValues;
```

That is slightly refined version, with 'implode' instead of another loop...

Comment: Thank you sir, Sir what you did is good but still i am getting [[0,1,2]] from each sub array as  output all i need is all 0 index for all sub arrays in one pocket like [[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]] and these sub arrays are from posted check boxes so index are auto thankyou

Comment: sir your earlier coding was very right but i was heaving only one problem in that, that is as i was getting [[subarray0, subarray1, subarray2]] but i need the value of [[subarray1_0, subarray2_0, subarray3)], and so on]

Comment: Great sir great you make my day Thankyou just one more thing can you modify this code just to remove if the value "none from output". i only wan to echo the numeric values.

Comment: i got it sir is_numeric is that key !